# How get a generated PIL image from Django REST framework backend to frontend?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I was planning to make a web app where I can make a POST request to generate an image with PIL on the backend and link it to the frontend through the REST framework by GET where I can download it. I don't want to save the generated image in the database. Just wanna generate it one time only for download. Any idea on how I can pull it off?

Comment: Have you considered returning the image as base64 encoded? Check this snippet https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10616/

Comment: I'll try that method.

Comment: @GabrielMuj Exactly what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: Can you please write your solution as a response to your own question, so that others can see it.

Comment: @GabrielMuj okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to generate the image without saving it on the folder. You basically save the image into bytes and convert to base64.

**views.py**

```
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def home(request):
  im_io = io.BytesIO()
  im = Image.new('RGBA', (300,300), (255, 214, 107))
  im_bg.text((10,0), test, fill='black')
  im.save(im_io, 'png', quality=70)
  im_io.seek(0)
  im_io_png = base64.b64encode(im_io.getvalue())
  context = im_io_png.decode('UTF-8')
  img_tag = mark_safe(f"<img src='data:image/png;base64, {context}'/>")
  return render(request, 'home.html', {'img_tag': img_tag })
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
  <h1>The Poster Generator </h1>
  <div>{{img_tag}}</div> <!-- Image will display here -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse), which allows you to send a FileField (or an ImageField, for that matter) as an http response.